# SF Compact Text in React Native

Tags: xcode, fonts, react-native, font-family

SF Compact Text doesn't seem to like the React Native environment very much when inserted as a custom font into XCode. Does anyone know how to properly reference the font? I've gone through all the necessary steps but when I try every variation of reference when using 'fontFamily' I seem not to get the text to show.

Do I include the hyphen? If I do then what is the 'fontWeight" of Medium?

It comes in the following types:

[image: SF Font Types in Xcode]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to print out all available fonts in your React Native app. To do so you need to go into your Xcode project and paste the following code into your project, for me I usually put it in AppDelegate.m under `NSURL *jsCodeLocation`:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
  NSLog(@”%@”, family);
  for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
  {
    NSLog(@” %@”, name);
  }
}
```

This should give you an output that looks like this:
[image]

You can use that to go through all of the fonts available, and use them in the way they are logged out. For example,

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'Zap Raygun V2.0'}}>This is Zap Raygun</Text>
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'Didot'}}>This is Didot</Text>
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'Menlo-BoldItalic'}}>This is Menlo-BoldItalic</Text>
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you!